# What ports does Selenium grid uses for heartbeat signals?

Tags: selenium, grid, port, heartbeat

I am trying to setup a testing environment using Selenium grid.  The hub is to be running on an AWS computer while the nodes would be executed on AWS Workspaces.  At this point, nodes can register in the hub, but about one minute latter, the hub complains stating:

`Marking the node http://192.168.x.x:1444 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries`

I have been doing some research and the problem seems to be that the hub sends heartbeat signals that do not reach the nodes and then it drops the session.  Since there is a firewall that might be blocking the heartbeat signals, I need to know which ports are used to send such signals in order to configure the firewall accordingly.

Thank you

---

Comment: This post should help you - you might need to use AWS Elastic IP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997652/what-ports-does-selenium-grid-uses-for-heartbeat-signals

Comment: Thanks Alin.  What post do you refer to?  The link you included in your comment points to my question.